# Não abrir teclado automaticamente quando entrar em tela com EditText

Tags: android

Tenho uma tela com um `EditText` ai sempre que eu entro nela já abre o teclado. Eu queria que só abrisse o teclado quando eu clicasse nele.

Eu tentei isso mas o teclado não está abrindo de jeito nenhum:

```
mItemDescriptionTextView.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver este problema abra o arquivo AndroidManifest.xml, daí na declaração da sua activity adicione a seguinte linha:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

O que vai fazer com que o teclado não apareça quando a activity for criado é o `keyboardHidden`.

Exemplo:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.activity.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 10):

Você precisa adicionar `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` dentro de seu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".SuaActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Essa flag irá esconder o teclado quando o usuário entrar em sua `Activity` (mesmo se o `EditText` tiver foco).

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode criar um método para esconder o teclado quando desejar, por exemplo:

```
public void hideKeyboard(View v) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu coloquei esses dois atributos em ContraintLayout e também funcionam

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use esses atributos no XML:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize esses atributos no seu XML onde está esse EditText, eu só consegui usar colocando esses atributos dentro de um LinearLayout como abaixo:

```
<LinearLayout          
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```